# Magento2 - Can you set category options during a product import?

Tags: csv, import, magento2

Coming from Magento1 and using the Magmi import tool I got accustomed to setting the category options directly in one of the csv columns by doing things like this when importing products via a CSV.
`"My Category::1::0::1/My Sub Category/My Sub Sub Category::1::0::0"`
Where the `::1::0::1` would set the following values:
`category name::[is_active]::[is_anchor]::[include_in_menu]` According to the documentation here: [Magmi - Setting Category Options During an import](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer). Is it possible to do the same thing in Magento 2 when importing products?

Cheers!